# Sketchware - Issues Publishing to Play Store

Tags: android, file, ide, google-play, sketchware

Using the Sketchware app and Android, I am trying to export to the Google Play store, I have to select the .json for the service account to allow it to publish the app.

However, when I try to select the .json file I have downloaded to my phone, I navigate to the directory the .json file is stored in then when I try to click on it, it is greyed out and I cannot click on it.

*(P.S.: I have tried contacting Sketchware support. However, it has been over three days now and I understand due to coronavirus the response may be delayed, but I thought I would ask here if anyone has a solution.)*

Answer (score 0):

Why are you publishing the app directly from Sketchware to PlayStore?

You better sign the apk usin APK SIGNER app and manually upload the APK to the Play Console.

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?

Comment: Related: *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, download Apk editor and select generic key or test key (try them out, there's a few) in settings in the app, and edit the API version to the correct number.  And set up a Google Play console account.

Comment: What is "Apk editor"? Is that the actual name of it?

Comment: What do you mean by "select three sign apk"? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67364176/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: wouldnt let me edit 4 some reason are u using Pro, if so go to https://t.me/sketchwarepro and look for JAMZ but i meant generic sign but mistype

Comment: Apk editor is a modded app that lets you edit the apk manifest, xmls, and files, but scratch all of this just download this https://github.com/Sketchware-Pro/Sketchware-Pro/releases/ its the original source for sketchware Pro, where you dont need apk editor and visit that Telegram

Answer (score -1):

I have never used Google Play Console before, but I think this could help you:

- Download your app
- Using Apk Extractor (play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ext.ui) is a software that will help you to get APK file from an pre installed app from Android ONLY. Using this software you can actually get an APK or Android Package that you can use while publishing app

There are many application available on Google Play that can convert your app file to [AAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_App_Bundle) format.

Comment: What do you mean by *"extract file APK"*? Can you elaborate? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72161778/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written right now).

Answer (score -4):

Yes, we do have a solution. Send the file to [WhatsApp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WhatsApp). Then share it from WhatsApp, choose file manager, copy the file to the place that you want, open sketchware, choose the file that you added in the JSON file, and enjoy.